# connection refused Laravel 5 with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel and I have a VM homestead set up in Vagrant. I have been having trouble connecting to my mongoDB database. I have so far added this [extension](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) to my laravel project with composer and followed its installation instructions. I have also also installed mongodb on homestead and it is reporting to be working. Now as I try to query something from my mongoDB I get the error:

```
MongoConnectionException in /home/vagrant/Code/flowtime/vendor/jenssegers/mongodb/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Connection.php line 152:
Failed to connect to: localhost:29911: Connection refused
```

I have checked the connection info several times and it is correct. So could someone tell me if it is related to my VM setup or something else?

Comment: Can you query MongoDB from the command line of your homestead instance?

Comment: You should check your credentials

Comment: yes i can @ajtrichards

Comment: i've copied them over from a cake project and checked them 100x times, may be there is some setting missing @AndreL

Comment: Are you connection credentials definitely being used to connect?